# Determine the roots of a Quadratic Equation

Tags: c, mathematics

A code that determines the roots of a quadratic equation.
Also, determine the following based on the discriminant *b² – 4ac*:

> If *b² − 4ac* is **positive**, display: “There are TWO REAL SOLUTIONS.”
>
> If *b² − 4ac* is **zero**, display: “There is ONLY ONE REAL SOLUTION.”
>
> If *b² − 4ac* is **negative**, display: “There are TWO COMPLEX SOLUTIONS.”

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int a, b, c, d;
    double root1_real, root2_real, root1_complex, root1_i, root2_complex, root2_i, root_zero;

    printf("Enter a, b and c where a*x*x + b*x + c = 0\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

    d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    
     if(d > 0){ // Positive
        root1_real = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2*a);
        root2_real = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2*a);
        printf("First Root : %.2lf\n", root1_real);
        printf("Second Root : %.2lf\n", root2_real);
        printf("There are TWO REAL SOLUTIONS\n");
     }else if(d < 0){ // Negative
        root1_complex = -b / (2 * a); root1_i = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);
        root2_complex = -b / (2 * a); root2_i = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);
        printf("First root : %.2lf + i%.2lf\n", root1_complex, root1_i);
        printf("Second root : %.2lf + i%.2lf\n", root2_complex, root2_i);
        printf("There are TWO COMPLEX SOLUTIONS\n");
     }else{ // Zero
        root_zero = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2*a);
        printf("Root : %.2lf\n", root_zero);
        printf("There is ONLY ONE REAL SOLUTION\n");
     }
     
     return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: In case `d < 0` you print two identical values. Copy-paste error?

Comment: What result would your want if `a==0` or `a==0 and `b==0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int main(void)` is preferable, as that's clear about the number of arguments.

I don't understand why the coefficients must be integers - surely a quadratic equation can have any real coefficients?

We don't test whether the `scanf()` actually converted all three inputs.  If we are given something that's not an integer (perhaps a different kind of number, perhaps just garbage input), then the program will proceed with incorrect data, and produce output that might be plausible, instead of a sensible error message.  We need something more like:

```
double a, b, c;
if (scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
   fputs("Invalid input\n", stderr);
   return 1;
}
```

There is another case of invalid input that's not checked - if `a` is zero, we don't want to divide by it.

You seem to have got confused which part is real and which imaginary here:

```
    root1_complex = -b / (2 * a); root1_i = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);
    root2_complex = -b / (2 * a); root2_i = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);
```

If we use better variable names, and reduce their scope a bit, we can make that simpler:

```
    double real = -b / (2 * a);
    double imag = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);
```

And we can do all the printing in a single call to `printf`:

```
    printf("First root : %.2f + i%.2lf\n"
           "Second root : %.2lf + i%.2lf\n"
           "There are TWO COMPLEX SOLUTIONS\n",
           real, -imag,   real, imag);
```

When we know `d` is zero, there's really no point computing its square root:

```
 } else { // Zero
    root_zero = -b / (2*a);
```

As suggested in a comment, it might also be worth computing that common part of the three expressions to outside the `if`/`else`:

```
const double real =  -b / a / 2;
if (d > 0) { // Positive
    double root = sqrt(d) / a / 2;
    ⋮
} else if (d < 0) { // Negative
    double imag = sqrt(-d) / a / 2;
    ⋮
} else { // Zero
    ⋮
}
```

---

Here's a lightly modified version with my suggestions applied:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a, b and c where ax² + bx + c = 0\n");
    double a, b, c;
    if (scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
        fputs("Invalid input\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!a) {
        fputs("Quadratic term must not be zero\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    const double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    printf("Finding the roots of %gx² + %gb + %g = 0\n", a, b, c);

    const double real =  -b / a / 2;
    if (d > 0) {
        double root = sqrt(d) / a / 2;
        printf("First Root: %.4g\n"
               "Second Root: %.4g\n"
               "There are TWO REAL SOLUTIONS\n",
               real - root,   real + root);
    } else if (d < 0) {
        double imag = sqrt(-d) / a / 2;
        printf("First root: %.4g + %.4gi\n"
               "Second root: %.4g + %.4gi\n"
               "There are TWO COMPLEX SOLUTIONS\n",
               real, -imag,   real, imag);
    } else { // d == 0
        printf("Root: %.4g\n"
               "There is ONLY ONE REAL SOLUTION\n",
               real);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, very good point (excuse the pun).

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.  Since the other review hits most of the important parts, I'll just mention a few things.

### Use standard library functions

Since C99, we have had `<complex.h>` which contains a number of handy [complex number](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex) functions and features.  Using them greatly simplifies the program:

```
// calculate the determinant
double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
// calculate the roots of the equation
double complex root[2] = { 
    (-b + csqrt(d))/2/a, 
    (-b - csqrt(d))/2/a
};
```

### Simplify printf statements

Using the above calculations, the printf statements become much simpler:

```
if (d > 0) {
    printf("First root : %.2lf\nSecond Root : %.2lf\n"
        "There are TWO REAL SOLUTIONS\n", 
        creal(root[0]), creal(root[1]));
} else if (d < 0) {
    printf("First root : %.2lf + i%.2lf\n"
           "Second Root : %.2lf + i%.2lf\n"
           "There are TWO COMPLEX SOLUTIONS\n", 
           creal(root[0]), cimag(root[0]), 
           creal(root[1]), cimag(root[1]));
} else {
    printf("Root : %.2lf\nThere is ONLY ONE REAL SOLUTION\n", 
        creal(root[0]));
}
```